# Sqlite exception: column not found

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I constructed the following database:

```
   private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TEST=
        " create table " + TABLE_TEST +
        " (test_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        COL_GRADE +" text not null," +
        DATE+" text not null);";



private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION=
        " create table " + TABLE_ANSWER +
        " (question_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
        COL_ANSWER_1+ " text not null,"+ 
        COL_ANSWER_2+" text not null," +
        COL_ANSWER_3+" text not null," +
        COL_ANSWER_4+" text not null," +
        COL_ANSWER_5+ " text not null,"+ 
        COL_ANSWER_6+" text not null," +
        COL_RIGHT_ANSWER+" integer," +
        COL_WRONG_ANSWER+" integer, " +
        COL_TEST_ID+" INTEGER, " + 
        "FOREIGN KEY(" + COL_TEST_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_TEST+"(test_id));";
```

The error persists so far:

> ```
> > 11-29 18:01:20.955: E/Database(853): Error inserting right_answer=6 wrong_answer=0 answer_5=fadsfas answer_6=gadsfdasasdfa
> ```
>
> answer_3=fasdfasf **test_id=1** answer_4=fasdfsa answer_1=fasdfasd
>   answer_2=fasdfas
>
> ```
> 11-29 18:01:20.955: E/Database(853): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table answer has no column
> ```
>
> named **test_id**: , while compiling: INSERT INTO answer(right_answer,
>   wrong_answer, answer_5, answer_6, answer_3, **test_id**, answer_4,
>   answer_1, answer_2) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("database", CREATE_TABLE_TEST); //I never see this statement in catlog
        Log.d("database", CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION); //nor this
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TEST);
    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_TEST);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_ANSWER);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

I put this in oncreate..:

```
 dbClass=new database(this);        
    try
    {
        Log.w("inside ",  " database opened");///This gets printed
        dbLite=dbClass.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.w("after ",  " database opened");///This get printed
    }
    catch(Exception c)
    {
        Log.v("Open database exception caught", c.getMessage());
        dbLite=dbClass.getReadableDatabase();
    }
```

Nothing in the onCreate gets printed..

It is as if onCreate never gets called

Comment: Can you give us your insert statements?  Also, on the References test clause do you maybe need to specify the table AND column (i.e. test.test_id)?

Comment: just before creating the table do this and post back the result
Log.d("database", CREATE_TABLE_TEST);
Log.d("database", CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION);

Comment: I dont see the statements printing out..... all I get is this before the exception happens 11-29 17:47:19.505: I/Database(671): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table answer has no column named test_id

Comment: if i click the second time, I get database not open.. :(

Comment: Probably a silly question, but is your code creating an empty database with no tables each time? And are you creating these 2 tables in your code each time you run your app before doing the insert?

Comment: For the not open exception do: dbLite.open() to open it, after that you can query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key isn't made correctly

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

for more information

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION=
" create table " + TABLE_ANSWER +
" (question_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
COL_ANSWER_1+ " text not null,"+ 
COL_ANSWER_2+" text not null," +
COL_ANSWER_3+" text not null," +
COL_ANSWER_4+" text not null," +
COL_ANSWER_5+ " text not null,"+ 
COL_ANSWER_6+" text not null," +
COL_RIGHT_ANSWER+" integer," +
COL_WRONG_ANSWER+" integer, " +
COL_TEST_ID+" INTEGER, " + 
"FOREIGN KEY(" + COL_TEST_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_TEST+"(test_id))";
```

should do the trick

furtermore your onCreate method only executes when the database gets created, not when upgraded
you should override onUpgrade to perform an update (or test on a new device/emulator)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)

if you extend sqliteOpenHelper then you need to call the super-constuctor with your newVersionId to trigger onUpgrade

```
public YourDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Tip: uninstall the application from your phone/emulator completely and reinstall it (then db will be removed and it will be created definately, if not the problem is somewhere else)

Comment: for some reason it didnt..I think the onCreate method in the database class, which I created, doesnt happen...see my question update in the end of my question...wait sorry..I do think you are right..let  me check yoru answer again

Comment: it still says it doesnt have the column test id..may be there is something wrong in the way the database opens?!?..It does insert test id..but it still shows the message

Comment: Did you change your newVersion int? otherwise the onUpgrade won't be triggered

Comment: public database(Context context) {
  super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_Version);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  
 }

Comment: The problem that onCreate doesnt get called when I call getWritableDatabase... I mean,,there is no exception thrown..the method is called,,but nothing inside the oncreate method is prited to the logcat

Comment: onCreate will only be called if you don't have a database and then you open one, if you already have a database then onUpgrade will be called (but only if you change your version number (for a higher one of course))

Answer (score 0):

Blind guess: do you need a `;` after `INTEGER REFERENCES test )` ?

Comment: i will check your answer..wait 1 min. no it still says I am missing a test_id

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out at me is the lack of spaces after the column name and before column type in the create table directive ...

COL_GRADE +"text not null," +
 DATE+"text not null);";

Are you sure the table actually was created correctly?

Comment: yeah, I used it to query its last id

Answer (score 0):

Can you try clearing the application data?  Sometimes the database gets created before you have all the columns in it and if your onUpgrade method is not implemented correctly the column never gets added until you clear the data.